# How to run Find.().One() in the new go-mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, error-handling, mongodb-query, mongo-go

Currently we are in the process of migrating the mgo([globalsign](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo#pkg-overview)) driver to go [mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.10.3/mongo#pkg-overview)

And I want some alternative way to do `Find.().One()`

I tried something like below but it did not help

```
    login = model.LoginModel{}
    err = mongo.Collection.Find(bson.M{"name": MAXCOUNT}).Decode(&loginCount)
```

Returned me back with the below error ,

```
 error was: cannot transform type []interface {} to a BSON Document: WriteArray can only write a Array while positioned on a Element or Value but is positioned on a TopLevel
```

not sure whether the new Decode method allows a struct value ?

my struct looks something like below

```
type LoginModel struct {
Username    string  `json:"username"`
Password    string  `json:"password"`

}
```

Do i need to have corresponding bson values too ?

Trying to run  Find.().One()  in  go-mongo-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Collection.Find()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.Find) is designed to query multiple elements. It returns a [`mongo.Cursor`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor) which you can use to iterate over the results or get all using [`Cursor.All()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Cursor.All).

If you need a single result, use [`Collection.FindOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.FindOne) instead.

For example:

```
ctx := context.Background() // Use / setup your context
c := ... // acquire mongo.Collection

var login model.LoginModel
err = c.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"name": MAXCOUNT}).Decode(&login)
// check error
```

Comment: I tried the way that you recommended but it gives me an error 
`mongo: no documents in result`

Comment: @karthickd That means the filter doesn't match any documents. What do you expect?

Comment: thanks for the response actually my DB had no document to match , was running my patch against a mongo container which had no results .

Comment: can I still use `Collection.Find()` to query single element? is there a way to do that ? 

Or let's say if the query contains more than one element then use `Find` else use `FindOne` , how to do that ? can I range over `[]primitive.M` and calculate the count of it say if its `gt` than 1 then use `Find()`

say in the below `bson.M` how to find the length of `[]bson.M`

`bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{{"alert": "WarningAlert"}, {"notification": "alertNotificiations"}}}`

Comment: @Karthik You may use `Collection.Find()` to exute any query, even those that result in 0, 1 or any number of elements. It returns a cursor, and you may choose to decode only a single result from it. The "size" of the filter has no correspondence to the number of results. You should know how many results you expect and use the proper method to query accordingly. You may of course use `Find()` in all cases, use `Cursor.All()` to get the results, and check how many results you actually got, which may be 0, 1, or more.